# Error: Cannot find module './development'

Tags: node.js

I am trying to clone and run this https://github.com/martijnboland/appoints-api-node.git

After cloning and doing `npm install`, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './development'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/appoints-api-node/config/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: Clone operation is successful .Error comes when i type node 'index.js' and try to run the app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a configuration file for the environment you are using. You can either create a `development.js` file manually in the `config` directory, or copy `config/example.js` to `config/development.js` and edit it appropriately.

Comment: I created a new file config/development.js and copied the contents of example.js in it but now i get this error Appoints service started on port 3000

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]

Comment: Do you have a MongoDB server running on port 27017?

Comment: Once i had the MongoDB server running on port 27017 the app started running and gave an error alhtough i dont think its related to this one .The error is " {"message":"Appoints service API","details":"This is a REST api where you can schedule appointments for ","_links":{"self":{"href":"/"},"me":{"href":"/me"},"appointments":{"href":"/appointments"}}}"

Comment: That's expected, see the Usage section in the README: https://github.com/martijnboland/appoints-api-node#usage